# Differential system $y'=2qy,\quad q'=-q^2+q$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{aligned} y' &= 2qy \\q' &= -q^2 + q \end{aligned}
I tried to solve this differential equation like this and I want to know if my approach is correct.
From the first equation, we have:

$$q = \frac{y'}{2y}$$

Substituting this into the second equation, we get:

$$\frac{y''}{2y} =  \frac{y'^2}{4y^2} + \frac{y'}{2y}$$

Simplifying this equation, we get:

$${y''}= {y'}$$

We can use the substitution $v = y'$ to transform it into a first-order equation:

$$v' = v$$
This equation can be solved using separation of variables.

Comment: $q^{'}=\frac{y^{''}-(y^{'})^2}{2y^2}$.  Why don't you first solve the equation for $q$ and then solve for $y$. Just separate variables

Comment: "Simplifying this equation, we get: $\frac{y''}{y} - \frac{y'^2}{y^2} = \frac{y'}{2y}$
": no, we get $y′′=y′.$ But actually, the mistake was before: "Substituting this into the second equation, we get: $\frac{y''}{2y} - \frac{y'^2}{4y^2} = - \frac{y'^2}{4y^2} + \frac{y'}{2y}$: no, we get $\frac{y''}{2y} - \frac{y'^2}{2y^2} = - \frac{y'^2}{4y^2} + \frac{y'}{2y}$

Comment: After this correction, you don't get $y''=y'$ any longer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normal form of differential equation $y'=y-y^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714323/normal-form-of-differential-equation-y-y-y2) It tells you how to solve *very simply* the second equation: $q=\frac{\lambda e^x}{1+\lambda e^x}.$ After that, solving the first one is obvious: $y=\mu(1+\lambda e^x)^2.$

Answer (score 1):

Well, the second equation is easy to solve:

$$\text{q}'\left(x\right)=\text{q}\left(x\right)-\left(\text{q}\left(x\right)\right)^2\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\int\frac{\text{q}'\left(x\right)}{\text{q}\left(x\right)-\left(\text{q}\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\int1\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Now, substitute $\text{u}=\text{q}\left(x\right)$. This gives:

$$\int\frac{1}{\text{u}-\text{u}^2}\space\text{du}=x+\text{C}\tag2$$

Now, I'll let you show that:

$$\int\frac{1}{\text{u}-\text{u}^2}\space\text{du}=-2\text{arctanh}\left(1-2\text{u}\right)+\text{C}\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$-2\text{arctanh}\left(1-2\text{q}\left(x\right)\right)=x+\text{C}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{q}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\tanh\left(\text{C}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\tag4$$

Solving the first equation, we get:

$$\text{y}'\left(x\right)=2\text{q}\left(x\right)\text{y}\left(x\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\int\frac{\text{y}'\left(x\right)}{\text{y}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x=\int2\text{q}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag5$$

Which gives:

$$\ln\left|\text{y}\left(x\right)\right|=\int\left(1-\tanh\left(\text{C}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\space\text{d}x=\int1\space\text{d}x-\int\tanh\left(\text{C}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\space\text{d}x\tag6$$

Which leads to:

$$\ln\left|\text{y}\left(x\right)\right|=x-2\ln\left|\cosh\left(\text{C}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|+\text{K}\tag7$$

Comment: For a (duplicate and) simpler solution, see last comment above.

Comment: Thank you so much!